# #Name? when opening Access report

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I am struggling with an access report that I have recently created. It was working fine until I was told I needed to add whitespace for paragraphs in text fields. To do this I wrapped the field with a replace function, replacing one CR-LF with two.
`=Replace([Brief problem statement],Chr(10),Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10))`

This was working fine, so I went ahead and used this function on all large text fields in my report.

Then I got a type error - circular reference. After researching, I realised it was because the control source used the control name. To fix this problem I added '1_' to the control name of each element. This then worked perfectly, so I closed the Access file.

An hour later, I re-opened the file and exported a report, only to find that for each field that had a function, there was a #Name? error. When I go into the property controls, all I need to do is refresh one of the fields control name, and then it seems to fix it all up.

I don't understand why this is happening, and I really can't have this happen each time I open the file.

All help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Story is as follows:
I open the report and it shows me this.
[Broken report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrqJp.png)

I go into property controls and update the control name, then the control source name. (I don't change it, just remove 1_ and replace it)
[Refreshing control source name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stul9.png)

This fixes it.
[Fixed report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtpQM.png)

But then when I close the file and reopen it, it reverts back to the broken picture.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem.  I set the report record source to a query and put the replace function in a calculated variable that targeted the table not a control and everything worked.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not 100% familiar with Access. I don't have a problem either until I close the file, and reopen it. The source for the report as a whole is a query that returns one line (i.e. I can produce only one report at a time). The replace function is in my control source using the field from the report itself. Is this the same? Thanks.

Comment: That expression in a textbox referencing a field of report RecordSource (maybe that's what @mazoula meant) should work just fine - does for me. Real issue is why isn't the control name getting committed when report is saved. I would normally use a prefix such as tbx in textbox name but I tested with 1_ and that worked.

Comment: My version of the report exported just fine.  My guess is you are still referring to the reports textbox "BriefProblem" rather than TheReportsQuery.[Brief Problem].  I put the replace function in a calculated variable in TheReportsQuery .  Then set control of the textbox "BriefProblem to the calculated variable.  I tested export to Excel and it worked.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Pre-process the field when generating the query and using that instead right? I thought of doing that, however the problem is I have many fields which I've done this to (brief problem was just the first example). I don't know if there is an easier way to apply one change to many fields in the query, or if I have to build a very long query to make this work.